# OpenSuse unbootable, grub uninstallable

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub, uefi

When I installed Kubuntu 18.04 onto my then new nvme drive, I simply created a GPT on it, then an ext4 partition `/dev/nvme0n1p1` and a swap partition `/dev/nvme0n1p2`. I left some space unallocated for a future system.

Now the time for that allocated space has come: I want to use OpenSuse. I let the installer do its automated thing (merely checked it wouldn't override my existing ext4 partition) and ended up with two new partitions in the previously unallocated area of the storage medium: `/dev/nvme0n1p3` is a fat16 partition according to KDE Partition Manager (the installer called it something like "v-fat") and `/dev/nvme0n1p4` is a btrfs partition.

My problem is that my computer still only boots Kubuntu. In grub, only this system is shown. The UEFI configuration thingy seems to view the entire nvme drive as a whole (even though it even splits thumb drives into anywhere between 2 and 5 parts).

I tried running `sudo update-grub` on Kubuntu. It didn't change anything.

I also tried running `sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1` and `sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p1`, both only resulting in error messages:

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
$ sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p1
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

I then read up on the problem and tried to install grub on the fat partition that the OpenSuse installer created:

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p3
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `fat' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1390431/499352) did not help either:

```
$ sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
```

How do I get my computer to boot OpenSuse?

Comment: Does the command `os-prober` on kubuntu find OpenSUSE?

Comment: That Grub wants a bios boot partition hints that it thinks the machine is booted in BIOS compatibility mode instead of UEFI. Is CSM enabled in the firmware setup?

Comment: @Rio6 `os-prober` doesn't print anything.

Comment: Btw. there is a HDD with a Windows installation in the computer too. Not even that one is listed.

Answer (score 1):

I went to the UEFI Settings and then Boot → UEFI Hard Disk Drive BBS Priorities. It had "Windows Boot ..." as the top priority. I changed it to "opensuse-secureboot". Then I went back to the general boot order and moved "UEFI Hard Disk:opensuse-secureboot" to the top.

I now am presented an OpenSuse-themed menu upon boot where I can choose between OpenSuse and Kubuntu. There even is a Windows entry which I assume would boot Windows if I chose it. :)

Answer (score 0):

> something like "v-fat"

This must be the ESP I mention below! The way you describe it, now, after reading again.

---

I think Johan is pointing in the right direction.

In the BIOS menu you can choose between "legacy bios" (=MBR) and "UEFI". You can even activate both at the same time. But that alone won't be enough.

When you "create a GPT" (simply or not) you also have options -- me I used that protective MBR, just in case.

Once you have reached grub, you can change the command line and put your new kernel, initrd and root. As I understand grub, it works by using filesystems, not blocklists (see error message in Q), so you just have to add a second menu entry, and maybe make it default. I am not surprised an installer didn't adapt to that situation. And why did you get a vfat and a btrfs partition?

After going again through the Q:

You seem to have no MBR ("this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition"). But where then is your **EFI System Partition**? That is where grub should go, and not to the newly created `/dev/nvme0n1p3.`

> The UEFI configuration thingy seems to view the entire nvme drive as a
>   whole (even though it even splits thumb drives into anywhere between 2
>   and 5 parts).

That is because the thumb drives contain partitions with bootable .EFI files (UEFI apllications: boot loaders and other utilities).

Your UEFI apparently knows of no boot loader on your drive. That would be done by `efibootmgr`, if inside linux.

You have a builtin boot loader, though: the UEFI Shell. It should be some kind of boot option in your UEFI BIOS menu.

With UEFI capable of starting grub (or systemd-boot, or...) in any partition, and with grub capable of loading a kernel image also from any partition, after a new installation, you only have to add a new menu entry for comfort. No real grub installation step is required.

> (merely checked it wouldn't override my existing ext4 partition)

YES. That was a good idea! And it says much about the quality of these installers.

Comment: So suse did everthing right, except putting the "Windows..." entry at the top? How did you boot before with Kubuntu? And do you know or care at all where your grub now is sitting?